# Windows firewall doesn't work

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall

I've added a rule to Windows firewall to block all incoming connections on port 80:

[image: rule]

But it has no effect - CurrPorts shows apache listening on port 80 and also nc (ncat on Win) shows port is still open.

Comment: So you have a rule that blocks INCOMING TCP port 80 traffic, so telnet from ANOTHER machine to `TELNET <machinename/IPAddress> 80` and conifm it cannot establish a connection. Otherwise, confirm that from an EXTERNAL machine that you are not able to connect to that machine's TCP port 80 interface if applicable. Check the Windows Event Viewer security logs to see the blocked traffic if you wish as well. You're not going to be able to emulate an incoming connection to that machine as the FW rule blocks from that same machine--test from another regardless of what's listening on that machine

Answer (score 2):

#### I've added a rule to Windows firewall to block all incoming connections on port 80

> But it has no effect - CurrPorts shows apache listening on port 80 and also nc (ncat on Win) shows port is still open.

You are using the wrong tools to determine whether the Firewall is doing its job.

`CurrPorts` and `nc`/`ncat` are showing **listening** ports.

That means there is a program listening on port 80. It does not mean traffic can actually reach that port.

You can run a program listening on any port and it can just sit there doing nothing at all.

Try using `telnet` (from a different PC).

Windows:

```
telnet ip_address 80
```

Unix:

```
telnet ip_address:80
```

If the Firewall is working you will get the response "timeout".

Comment: So the problem is that i run the tools locally not from the remote host?

Comment: The problem is you are checking the firewall with the wrong tools. The firewall is configured to block incoming connections so you need to create a connection from outside the firewall to see if it is blocked. That's what telnet from another machine will do, as I clearly explained in the answer.

Comment: Will nc from another machine work to?

Comment: I've no idea. I don't have it and I've never user it.